# dual monitors - adjust backlight brightness on just one?

Tags: multiple-monitors, sync

Are there any monitors that sync their settings? For example, you dim the brightness on one and have the second monitor do the same.

Comment: It's kind of hard to do that, even with two monitors that are the same brand, because every monitor has a different idea of what 100% brightness ought to be.

Comment: yeah i guess that is true, I should stop being so lazy - its just I have to go from 80 down to 0 over the course of the day to remain at a good level or keep the curtains closed...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you, instead of continuously updating hardware settings, go the software way, with [f.lux and other similar softwares](http://alternativeto.net/software/f46lux/) ...